# Install4j: changing size of a JPanel in custom InstallerScreen

Tags: java, swing, install4j

I am trying to change the size of the `JPanel` which is to be returned in `createComponent()` and adjust it to the size of the Frame/ the screen using `getParent()`. but the panels size remains unchanged. The code for my CustomPanel follows:

```
    class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
        final Image backImage = getBackImage();

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(backImage, 0, 0, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Container c = this.getParent();
            Dimension d = new Dimension(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
            return d;
        }
    }
```

and the sample code inside the `createComponent()` method follows:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new CustomPanel();
buttonPanel.add(button);    
return buttonPanel;
```

I have tried to do it directly when instantiating the `buttonPanel` which gave me error. The sample code for this is:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
Container c = buttonPanel.getParent();
Dimension d = new Dimension(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
buttonPanel.setSize(d);
buttonPanel.add(button);
return buttonPanel;
```

and the error log is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.customcode.SampleScreenNew.createComponent(SampleScreenNew.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.addScreenContent(ScreenEnvelope.java:372)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.StandardScreen.createMainPanel(StandardScreen.java:136)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.StandardScreen.setupComponent(StandardScreen.java:78)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.StandardScreen.initScreen(StandardScreen.java:50)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.init(ScreenEnvelope.java:61)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.<init>(ScreenEnvelope.java:46)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.WizardScreenExecutor$1.run(WizardScreenExecutor.java:199)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"I am trying to change the size of the JPanel which is to be returned in createComponent() and adjust it to the size of the Frame/ the screen using getParent()."*  Seems like the tail wagging the dog.  In this case, I would recommend either of 1) Have the panel return a sensible preferred size and `pack()` the top level container, or.. 2) Do that same thing, then follow it with setting the top level container (the frame) to `MAXIMIZED_BOTH` to have it fill the screen. -- In both case, the panel should probably be in a layout/layout constraint that will cause it to expand with the window.

Comment: As an aside:  The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @AndrewThompson the problem is for **Install4j** application I can only find libraries of install4j that uses java swing. And they have specific abstract classes that you have to extend for creating custom screens for your installer app. Plus this is only the second time I am ever trying to use java swing, things are kinda still alien for me

Comment: *"the problem is for Install4j application"*  Use JWS instead.  Problem solved!

Comment: @AndrewThompson install4j and JWS are not in the same category. Not trying to make a list here, but one simple difference is: How you would you deploy a server application with JWS?

Comment: *"How you would you deploy a server application with JWS?"* Use the   [`ExtensionInstallerService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html) to invoke the installer..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I really don't think that this is useful for installing a service on Windows, for example. As an aside: If someone asks a question about a particular technology, recommending a different technology is bad form.

Comment: *"..recommending a different technology is bad form."*  Not here it isn't.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your role in this question is entirely non-constructive. I suggest you think about that a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screen implementation, override

```
@Override
public boolean isFillVertical() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isFillHorizontal() {
    return true;
}
```

Then the panel returned by `createComponent()` will fill all the available space.